# In Spring MongoDB group by one column and get sum of another two field

Tags: spring, mongodb

I have a feed collection with sample data like :

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("55deb33dcb9be727e8356289"),
"userName" : "John",
"likeCount" : 2,
"commentCount" : 10,
}
,
{
"_id" : ObjectId("55deb33dcb3456e33434d456"),
"channelName" : "Mark",
"likeCount" : 5,
"commentCount" : 10,
},
{
"_id" : ObjectId("55acd3434324acd3e4567567"),
"userName" : "John",
"likeCount" : 12,
"commentCount" : 15,
}
```

I want to get all the records with group by "userName" and sum of "likeCount" + "commentCout".
 In Mysql we use :

```
select userName,sum(likeCount)+sum(commentCount) as "totalCount"  from feed group by userName
```

How can I write the aggregation for above query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this can be achieved by adding an extra field that adds the `likeCount` and `commentCount` fields in the **[`$project`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** stage, then do the sum operation on that field for documents grouped by the `userName` key. Something like this in mongo query:

```
db.feed.aggregate([
    {
        "$project": {
            "userName": 1,
            "sumLikeAndCommentCounts": {
                "$add": [ "$likeCount", "$commentCount" ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$userName",
            "totalCount": {
                "$sum": "$sumLikeAndCommentCounts"
            }
        }
    }
])
```

**OR**

you just have one pipeline step **[`$group`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** where you can plug in the addition operation as an expression for the **[`$sum`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum)**:

```
db.feed.aggregate([    
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$userName",
            "totalCount": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$add": [ "$likeCount", "$commentCount" ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Both of the above operation pipelines will yield the result (for the given sample data):

```
{ "_id" : null, "totalCount" : 15 }
{ "_id" : "John", "totalCount" : 39 }
```

The Spring Data MongoDB aggregation equivalent is based on the first example, with an option of using the [**SpEL `andExpression`**](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.aggregation.examples.example5) in the projection operation:

```
Aggregation agg = Aggregation.newAggregation( 
    project("id", "userName") 
        .and("likeCount").plus("commentCount").as("sumLikeAndCommentCounts"),
        //.andExpression("likeCount + commentCount").as("sumLikeAndCommentCounts"), <-- or use expressions
    group("userName").sum("sumLikeAndCommentCounts").as("totalCount")
); 
AggregationResults<FeedsTotal> result = 
mongos.aggregate(agg, this.getCollectionName(), FeedsTotal.class);
```

Comment: Thanks chridam... for your help

Comment: No worries @Pankaj :-)